# Trying to query based on selected feature, but query is using previously selected feature

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I'm not sure how to replicate this problem with just a code snippet, because it involves so many different elements of my HTML and JS. So here is a [jsbin with the whole code](http://jsbin.com/netavehomu/edit?js,console,output).

I use ESRI's `popup` widget to populate the sidebar with data from the selected feature, and it works. Except for one bit where I'm running a function `pctile` after selecting the feature (line 1376 in my JavaScript).

`pctile` should give me a value `P` that is the percentile rank of the currently selected tract.

If you watch the console while clicking census tracts in the map, you can see that line 1408 writes the value `P` of the previously selected tract ("P from buildHeader"). After that, the function `pctile` fires, updating the value of `P` to the current tract ("P:").

How can I ensure that `pctile` fires and updates `P` before I try to use it in my function `buildHeader` (line 1403)?

**UPDATE** I think the solution involves using callbacks. I'm trying to make that work now.

**Update** I have tried using callbacks, but I'm not sure that solution works in this context. Because the function I want to pass as the callback argument is my buildHeader function that returns HTML to insert into a div. From what I understand you can't get a return from a callback function.